# c++ Leaderboard output from external txt file not working

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Hello I have been trying to do a program where the compiler takes from a txt file scores and outputs them in ascending order but it is not working any ideas on what is wrong? And how would I be able to turn this into a array?

Here is my infile.txt that I am working with:

```
1 John Doe     23567
2 Larry Bird       21889
3 Michael Jordan   21889
4 James Bond       13890
5 Gary Smith       10987
6 GJ               9889
7 Vivien vien      8990
8 Samantha Carl    6778
9 Gary  Lewes      5667
10 Sybil Saban     4677
```

The program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using std::ifstream;
using namespace std;


int main ()
{
    ifstream file_("infile.txt");
    int highscore;
    std::string name;
    int id;
    if (file_.is_open())
    {
    while(file_>>id >> name >> highscore)
    {

        std::cout<<id << " " <<name << " " <<highscore<<"";
    }
    file_.close();

    }


system ("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
file_>> id >> name >> highscore
```

only the first name is read, nothing is read into `highscore`, the stream goes into a state of error, and the loop breaks right away.

You need to use:

```
std::string firstName;
std::string lastNmae;

file_ >> id >> firstName >> lastName >> highscore
```

---

**Update**

The presence of

```
6 GJ               9889
```

in the file makes it difficult for simple reading of the file. You have to use a totally different strategy.

1. Read the file line by line.
2. Tokenize each line.
3. Extract the ID from the first token.
4. Extract the high score from the last token.
5. Combine the middle tokens to form the name.

Here's what I am thinking of:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::ifstream;
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   ifstream file_("infile.txt");

   int highscore;
   std::string name;
   int id;
   if (file_.is_open())
   {
      std::string line;
      while ( getline(file_, line) )
      {
         std::string token;
         std::istringstream str(line);
         std::vector<std::string> tokens;
         while ( str >> token )
         {
            tokens.push_back(token);
         }

         size_t numTokens = tokens.size();
         if ( numTokens < 2 )
         {
            // Problem
         }
         else
         {
            id = std::stoi(tokens[0]);
            highscore = std::stoi(tokens.back());

            name = tokens[1];
            for ( size_t i = 2; i < numTokens-1; ++i )
            {
               name += " ";
               name += tokens[i];
            }

            std::cout << id << " " << name << " " << highscore << std::endl;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: But I wish for everything in my text file to come up not just the beggining.

Comment: I tried using your strategy but I just get a it has exited with code 0 error.

Comment: Are you saying there is no output? In that case, your program is not finding he input file.

Comment: I am confused if that is the case since I am sure that I have linked my file successfully and it is called infile.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Collect all of these data points in a struct, and parse your input into an array of these structs.

When parsing the input, you need to note:
1) how >> actually works
2) the input file specified has names as 1 and 2 words
3) strings have access to the += operator which may be handy.

After completing this, you will want to sort this array of structs by their score member, then output the array in order.